# Find average of values over certain row number pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe set up like this.

```
    Date    Daily Risk Score
0   2020-06-26  6.0
1   2020-06-27  6.0
2   2020-06-28  6.0
3   2020-06-29  6.0
4   2020-06-30  6.0
5   2020-07-01  6.0
6   2020-07-02  6.0
7   2020-07-03  6.0
8   2020-07-04  6.0
9   2020-07-05  6.0
10  2020-07-06  6.0
11  2020-07-07  6.0
12  2020-07-08  6.0
13  2020-07-09  6.0
14  2020-06-26  6.0
15  2020-06-27  6.0
16  2020-06-28  6.0
17  2020-06-29  6.0
18  2020-06-30  6.0
19  2020-07-01  6.0
20  2020-07-02  6.0
21  2020-07-03  6.0
22  2020-07-04  6.0
23  2020-07-05  6.0
24  2020-07-06  6.0
25  2020-07-07  6.0
26  2020-07-08  6.0
27  2020-07-09  6.0
```

I want to take the average of all the similar days throughout the entire dataframe (50k+ entries). How do I iterate over each date to then create one column at the end that list 14 values, which correspond to the mean of each day?

Expected output would be:

```
  Date  Daily Risk Score  Mean
0   2020-06-26  6.0   a
1   2020-06-27  6.0   b
2   2020-06-28  6.0   c 
3   2020-06-29  6.0   ...
4   2020-06-30  6.0
5   2020-07-01  6.0
6   2020-07-02  6.0
7   2020-07-03  6.0
8   2020-07-04  6.0
9   2020-07-05  6.0
10  2020-07-06  6.0
11  2020-07-07  6.0
12  2020-07-08  6.0
13  2020-07-09  6.0
14  2020-06-26  6.0
15  2020-06-27  6.0
16  2020-06-28  6.0
17  2020-06-29  6.0
18  2020-06-30  6.0
19  2020-07-01  6.0
20  2020-07-02  6.0
21  2020-07-03  6.0
22  2020-07-04  6.0
23  2020-07-05  6.0
24  2020-07-06  6.0
25  2020-07-07  6.0
26  2020-07-08  6.0
27  2020-07-09  6.0
```

Where a represents the mean of all of the Daily Risk Score on 6-26. B is mean of all on 6-27 and so forth.

Comment: `df.Value.iloc[::3].mean()`?

Comment: For all rows, so gruoping them all in this way? Please share expected output

Comment: How would I move onto the next set then? Say I wanted to start with the second value (2). Would it be df['Value'].iloc[1:3].mean()?

Comment: It has to be for all rows @Ch3steR

Comment: the syntax is df['Value'].iloc[start:stop:step], so df.iloc[::3] starts at 0, stops at the end of rows and iterates 3 items at a time. To start at row 2, use df.iloc[1::3] (starts at index 1/row 2, iterates 3 items at a time until end of rows)

Comment: So, the mean of 3rd entry would be `(3+1+4)/3`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a numpy based approach, taking a rolling window view of the column values using [`view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows), with a step size of `3`. With this approach, if the whole window is not present, the output is omitted.

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

a = df['Value'].to_numpy()
# strided view of a with a step size of 3
w = view_as_windows(a, len(a)//3, step=3)
# missing values not present in strided view (incomplete window)
missing = a[w.size:]
prev_means = w.mean(0)
# construct new array with missing values and means of w
# if no missing values, the mean is kept
prev_means[:len(missing)] = a[w.size:]
means = np.vstack([w, prev_means]).mean(0)
# new df column
new_col = np.full(len(a), np.nan)
new_col[:len(means)] = means
df['means'] = new_col
```

---

```
print(df)

    Value     means
0       1  3.000000 # (1+4+2+5)/4
1       2  4.000000 # (2+5+3+6)/4
2       3  2.666667 # (3+1+4)/3
3       4       NaN
4       5       NaN
5       1       NaN
6       2       NaN
7       3       NaN
8       4       NaN
9       5       NaN
10      6       NaN
```

Comment: I edited my original question to better reflect what exactly I am looking for. Sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) with [`np.nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html)

```
def mean_window(arr, s):
    l = len(arr)
    fill_values = (s - l%s) if l%s else 0
    return np.nanmean(np.r_[arr,[np.nan]*fill_values].reshape(-1,s),axis=0)

mean_window(df.Value.to_numpy, 3)
# array([3.        , 4.        , 2.66666667])
```

#### Details

```
def mean_window(arr, s):
    l = len(arr)
    fill_values = (s - l%s) if l%s else 0
    print(np.r_[arr,[np.nan]*fill_values].reshape(-1,s)

mean_window(df.Value.to_numpy(), 3)
# [[ 1.     2.        3.]
#  [ 4.     5.        1.]
#  [ 2.     3.        4.]
#  [ 5.     6.       nan]]
#     |      |          |
# arr[::3] arr[1::3] arr[2::3]

mean_window(df.values.to_numpy(), 4)
# [[ 1.     2.       3.        4.]
#  [ 5.     1.       2.        3.]
#  [ 4.     5.       6.       nan]]
#    |      |         |         |
# arr[::4] arr[1::4] arr[2::4] arr[3::4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[::3]['Value'].mean()
```

This gets what you want, but you wanted to also assign it to a column right, how would you want that result to look like?

Comment: The column name will be a date which I can assign myself, but ideally it would just be one row with the mean value.